# PostgreSQL define user parameter for command line psql.exe

Tags: postgresql, windows-7

How do I define the *user* for PostgreSQL on the command line?

If I want to sign in as *root* I would use the following with MySQL...

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Also is there a way to list users? I'm connected via pgAdmin III so if a list is available there I just haven't found it.

Comment: `psql --help` will tell you. Or simply read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name, programs use `/?` to list parameters by default. The following is the default user without a password (even though the setup process asked for a password and it does not match for the default user on the command prompt but it does in phAdmin III).

```
psql --username=postgres
```

Comment: Well, Postgres comes from a Linux/Unix environment and there, help is obtained using `--help`. But this is all documented in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `U` parameter as following:

```
psql -U name_of_user
```

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)